# Show only what is outside of div. kind of like the opposite of overflow: hidden;

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have the same problem and I don't know how to do it. I have a title and both the title and the outlined box are in a container div together. I offset-ed the outlined box for the design. I want what is inside the container divto not show but what is outside to do. If you don't understand here are some pictures.

[image - container shown as thin blue border, outline box as thick orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hVSD.jpg)

[this is with overflow: hidden; on the container.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbZ1n.jpg)

Here's how the code's looking:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 20%;

  width: 450px;
  height: 150px;
  
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 2px solid #0d00ff;

}

.slog-box{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: -25px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 5px solid #ff6600;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
            <div class="slog-box"></div>
            <p class="slogan" id="slogan">
                    el rujido se escucha
                    entre las montañas
            </p>
     </div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

you see, I want to accomplish the opposite of what overflow hidden does. anyone know? would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You need the container to be pos relative to get an idea of the slogan size, then you set the slog-box to be pos absolute, you can set bigger width on it and offset it. Remove overflow hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.slog-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -30px;
  left: 30px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

.slogan {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8uzwcy5d/3/